# "Attack someone unprepared" or "be attacked unprepared"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one should I say:

> They attacked me **unprepared.**

Or

> I was attacked **unprepared.**

Do these sentences have any similarities with:

> He died **young?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer below is helpful, please upvote it and/or mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> They attacked me unprepared

This is a bit ambiguous.  Most likely it means

**They attacked me, but they were unprepared.**

But it could also mean

**They attacked me, and I was unprepared for it.**

The context will tell you which one is meant.

> I was attacked unprepared

This unambiguously means

**I was attacked, and I was unprepared for it.**